# ReactJS: Props or State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a simple to do list using react js. App has some actions that are combined into lists of actions.
The structure of classes looks like that:

> App
>
> ---GroupOfActions
>
> ------ListOfActionsRow
>
> ------ActionRow

All data stores in global var actions which looks like (it's a global var):

> var actions=[    {list:'some list', color:'#79fa5f', name:'some
>   action', priority:'0', done:true}]

When user change name of action or name of list, it should be changed in "actions" and in DOM. I can change it in "action", but what is the best pattern to change it in DOM?
Now i'm using props. Here is the part of my code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
  super(props);
  actions=[];
    //parsing actions from localStorage
 } 
 
 render() {
  return(
       <GroupOfActions actions={actions} />
     );
 }
}

class GroupOfActions extends React.Component {  
 render (){
  var rows=[];
  var lastList=null;
  this.props.actions.forEach(function(action){
   if (action.list!==lastList){
    rows.push(<ListOfActionsRow list={action.list} key={action.list} color={action.color} />);
   }
   rows.push(<ActionRow action={action} color={action.color} list={action.list}  key={action.name} />);
   
   lastList=action.list;
  });
  
  return(
  <div className="container" >
  {rows}   
  </div>
  );
 }
}

class ActionRow extends React.Component {

onNameChange(){
  var targetAction=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('{\"list\":\"'+
                  this.props.list+
      '\",\"color\":\"'+
      this.props.color+
      '\",\"name\":\"'+
      this.props.action.name+
      '\",\"priority\":\"'+
      this.props.action.priority+
      '\",\"done\":'+
      this.props.action.done+
      '}'));
  console.log(targetAction);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(actions));
  var toDoList=JSON.stringify(actions);
  var startIndex=toDoList.indexOf(targetAction);
  var endIndex=startIndex+targetAction.length;
  if (startIndex>-1){
   var nameStartIndex=targetAction.indexOf('\",\"name\":\"');
   var nameEndIndex=targetAction.indexOf('\",\"priority\":\"');
   toDoList=toDoList.substring(0,startIndex)
           +toDoList.substring(startIndex,(nameStartIndex+11))
     +this.refs.newName.value
     +toDoList.substring(nameEndIndex+1);
   console.log(toDoList);
   localStorage.setItem('toDoList',toDoList);
   actions=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('toDoList'));
   console.log(actions);
   this.props.action.name=this.refs.newName.value;
  } else {console.log(startIndex);}
 }



 render () {
  return (
  <div>
     <div className={'row '+(this.state.edition?'hidden':'')} >
        <div className="col-md-3" ref='oldName' onClick={this.editActionRow}>{this.props.action.name}</div>
              <div className="col-md-1" onClick={this.editActionRow} style={{width:'20%'}}>{this.props.action.priority}</div>
     <div className="col-md-1" onClick={this.editActionRow}><input type='checkbox' ref='oldDone' checked={this.props.action.done} /></div>
     </div>
        <div className={'row '+(this.state.edition?'':'hidden')}>
     <div className="col-md-6" onClick={this.editActionRow} style={{backgroundColor:'#fafafa'}}>
          <input type='text' ref='newName' defaultValue={this.props.action.name} onChange={this.onNameChange} />
               <label>Priority</label>
               <select defaultValue={this.props.action.priority} onChange={this.onPriorityChange} ref='newPriority'>
                   <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
               </select>
               <label>Done</label>
               <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked={this.props.action.done} ref='newDone' onChange={this.onDoneChange} />
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

class ListOfActionsRow extends React.Component {
 onNameOfListChange() {
  var oldNameOfList=this.props.list;
  var newNameOfList=this.refs.newNameOfList.value;
  var toDoList=JSON.stringify(actions);
  var newToDoList;
  for (var i=0;i<toDoList.length;i++) {
   var nameIndex=toDoList.indexOf(oldNameOfList,i);
   if (nameIndex==-1) continue;
   i=nameIndex;
   var nameEndIndex=nameIndex+oldNameOfList.length;
   newToDoList=toDoList.substring(0,nameIndex)
           +newNameOfList
           +toDoList.substring(nameEndIndex);
  } 
   
  console.log(newToDoList);
  localStorage.setItem('toDoList',newToDoList);
  actions=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('toDoList'));
  console.log(actions);
  this.props.list=this.refs.newNameOfList.value;
  
 }
 
 render() {
  return (
  <div>
     <div className={'row '+(this.state.editionOfList?'hidden':'')} >
        <div className="col-md-6" onClick={this.editListRow} >
           <div className="well well-small lead" style={{backgroundColor:'{this.props.color}'}} style={{marginTop:'20px'}} ref='oldNameOfList'>
              {this.props.list}
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div className={'row '+(this.state.editionOfList?'':'hidden')} >
     <div className="col-md-6" >
        <div className="well well-small lead" onClick={this.editListRow} style={{backgroundColor:'#fafafa'}}>
        <input type='text' ref='newNameOfList' defaultValue={this.props.list} onChange={this.onNameOfListChange} />
               <label>Color</label>
               <select>
                   <option value="0">Yellow</option>
                <option value="1">Blue</option>
                <option value="2">Green</option>
               </select>
     </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div className="row" style={{marginBottom:'20px'}}>
         <div className="col-md-2">
     </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

In class ActionRow line

```js
this.props.action.name=this.refs.newName.value;
```

works correct. In ListOfActionRow similar line makes an error:

```js
this.props.list=this.refs.newNameOfList.value;
```

May be using props is anti-pattern in this case? Why the same command works in one case but doesn't work in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a correct way to mutate the props like `this.props.action.name=this.refs.newName.value;`, The ideal way would be pass on a function from the parent component to the child component and call it from the child component which sets a value in the parent and then passes on to child

Also React DOCS recommend to make use of `callback` approach for `refs` rather than the string approach

For instance in the App component create a function to change the list name

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        actions=[];
    //parsing actions from localStorage
    }   
    changeListName = (val) => {
            /// take action here
    }
    render() {
        return(
          <GroupOfActions actions={actions} changeListName = {(val) => {this.changeListName}}/>
        );
    }
}


class GroupOfActions extends React.Component {   
    render (){
        var rows=[];
        var lastList=null;
        this.props.actions.forEach((action) =>{
            if (action.list!==lastList){
                rows.push(<ListOfActionsRow list={action.list} key={action.list} color={action.color} changeListName={(val) => this.props.changeListName(val)}/>);
            }
            rows.push(<ActionRow action={action} color={action.color} list={action.list}  key={action.name} />);

            lastList=action.list;
        });

        return(
        <div className="container" >
        {rows}          
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class ListOfActionsRow extends React.Component {
    onNameOfListChange() {
        var oldNameOfList=this.props.list;
        var newNameOfList=this.refs.newNameOfList.value;
        var toDoList=JSON.stringify(actions);
        var newToDoList;
        for (var i=0;i<toDoList.length;i++) {
            var nameIndex=toDoList.indexOf(oldNameOfList,i);
            if (nameIndex==-1) continue;
            i=nameIndex;
            var nameEndIndex=nameIndex+oldNameOfList.length;
            newToDoList=toDoList.substring(0,nameIndex)
                    +newNameOfList
                    +toDoList.substring(nameEndIndex);
        } 

        console.log(newToDoList);
        localStorage.setItem('toDoList',newToDoList);
        actions=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('toDoList'));
        console.log(actions);
        this.props.changeListName(this.newNameOfList.value);

    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
           <div className={'row '+(this.state.editionOfList?'hidden':'')} >
              <div className="col-md-6" onClick={this.editListRow} >
                 <div className="well well-small lead" style={{backgroundColor:'{this.props.color}'}} style={{marginTop:'20px'}} ref={(list) => {this.oldNameOfList}}>
                    {this.props.list}
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div className={'row '+(this.state.editionOfList?'':'hidden')} >
           <div className="col-md-6" >
              <div className="well well-small lead" onClick={this.editListRow} style={{backgroundColor:'#fafafa'}}>
                 <input type='text' ref={(list) => {this.newNameOfList}} defaultValue={this.props.list} onChange={this.onNameOfListChange} />
                        <label>Color</label>
                        <select>
                            <option value="0">Yellow</option>
                            <option value="1">Blue</option>
                            <option value="2">Green</option>
                        </select>
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div className="row" style={{marginBottom:'20px'}}>
               <div className="col-md-2">
           </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for explanation! i'm trying to do smth like this: 
in App 
changeListName(val) {
        //
    }
in GroupOfActions
rows.push(<ListOfActionsRow changeListName={this.props.changeListName.bind(this)} list={action.list} key={action.list} color={action.color} />);

and in this line i have an error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Comment: you need to bind the forEach function Use `this.props.actions.forEach((action)=> {`

Comment: Above is not a tested working code, I wanted to give an idea on how to achieve what you wanted